# Running interactive Bash commands over ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, chef-infra

I am trying to automate my server provisioning process using chef. Since I don't want to run chef as root, I need a chef/deployer user. But I don't want to create this user manually. Instead, I want to automate this step. So I took a shot at scripting it but ran into an issue:

The problem is that if I run

```
>ssh root@123.345.345.567 '/bin/bash -e' < ./add_user.sh
```

where add_user contains

```
//..if the username doesnt exist already
adduser $USERNAME --gecos ''
```

I never see the output or the prompts of the command.

1. Is there a way to run interactive commands in this way?
2. Is there a better way to add users in an automated fashion?

Comment: `echo "command" | ssh user@remote_host`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
ssh -t root@<ipaddress> adduser $USERNAME --gecos
```

Not sure why you have a `$` in the IP address in your original example - that's likely to cause `ssh` to fail to connect, but since you didn't indicate that sort of failure, I'm assuming that's just a typo.

Since `add_user.sh` is just a simple command, there's no need for the added complexity of explicitly running `bash` or the redirection, just run the `adduser` command via `ssh`.

And lastly, since `$USERNAME` is likely defined on the local end, and not on the remote end, even if you could get your original command to "do what you said", you'd end up running `adduser  --gecos` on the remote end, which isn't what you intended.

Comment: I removed the $ from the IP (typo). There is in fact a check for the pre-existence of the user in the script. That's the only reason why its still a script.

Answer (score 0):

Try using :

```
ssh -t root@$123.345.345.567 '/bin/bash -e' < ./add_user.sh
```

instead.

Comment: I tried this and got:
>> Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.

So I looked up the interwebz and found that -t -t should force it. But that just prints the contents of the shell script to the terminal console.

Comment: When I remove the "-e" with the "-t -t", the script actually runs but doesnt seem to be accepting my user input and continuing. Its stuck on waiting for me to enter something even though I did.