# Customize linux terminal PS1 variable in a function before starting a session

Tags: linux, bash, session, terminal, ps1

I often start a terminal session to servers from different tabs of my terminal. I would like to create a function that before starting the session it changes the title of the tab so that I can easily recognize which tab has which session open.

Let's pretend here that my session is an ssh session. When I type in terminal

```
fn myserver
```

where fn is a function defined in ~/.bashrc:

```
function fn() {
  set-title "$1"
  ssh $1         
}
function set-title() {
  if [[ -z "$ORIG" ]]; then
    ORIG=$PS1
  fi
  TITLE="\[\e]2;$*\a\]"
  PS1=${ORIG}${TITLE}
}
```

the terminal starts the session and the title for the tab is changed ONLY AFTER the ssh session ends. I guess that this come because the session is open in the fn function, and only when the function returns is PS1 actualized. How to change the title/update the PS1 variable BEFORE the session begins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct; your local host does not display another prompt after you add `TITLE` to `PS1` until after `ssh` exits. Instead, just output `TITLE` immediately.

```
function fn() {
  set-title "$1"
  ssh $1         
}
function set-title() {
  printf '\e]2;%s\a' "$1"
}
```

Note that setting `PS1` locally before running `ssh` has no effect on your prompt on the remote host anyway.

Comment: Thank you! Could you kindly explain what this is doing? I guess printf replaces %s and prints to terminal, but I am a bit at loss about \e]2;%s\a

Comment: It's the same text you were placing in your prompt; the `%s` is a format specification that `printf` replaces with its next argument `($1)`. It's generally good practice to do this rather than putting parameter expansions directly in the first argument to `printf`, to avoid accidentally treating embedded `%` characters as the start of a format specification.

Comment: I know about printf, and honestly I just found the \[\e]2;$*\a\] text from another forum without knowing what that exactly does. But it works. Thank you again!

Comment: Quick overview: `\[` and `\]` are only needed in `PS1`; they tell `bash` that the characters contained within don't occupy any space when output, which helps `bash` keep track of the cursor position when editing a command line. `\e]2;...\a` is an xterm control sequence that directs the terminal to display the `...` in the title bar rather than directly on the terminal screen.

Answer (score 1):

Using details from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13203391/3631760), I came up with this:

```
function set-title() {
  if [[ -z "$ORIG" ]]; then
    ORIG=$PS1
  fi
  TITLE="\[\e]2;$*\a\]"
  PS1=${ORIG}${TITLE}
}

function fn() {
  set-title $1
  ssh -t $1 "bash --init-file <(echo \"export PS1=\\\"$ORIG$TITLE\\\"\")"
}
```

You may have to source your `.bashrc` file before exporting `PS1` since `--init-file` makes `bash` ignore initialization files. (I didn't need to for some reason...). Then you should replace `echo \"export PS1=\\\"$ORIG$TITLE\\\"\"` with `echo \"cd $HOME; . .bashrc; export PS1=\\\"$ORIG$TITLE\\\"\"`